# Unhandled promise failed to connect Database in 15000ms

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```
let obj = columnparam;

function promise(setname){
      let query1= `select id from tablename where name= '${setname}'`;
      let sql_service = new IHCM.SqlService();
      sql_service.connection().connect().then(sql_connect => {
        return sql_connect.request().query(query1).then(output_result => {
          let result= output_result['recordset'][0]['id']
        })
          .catch(error => {
            throw new Error(`Failed due to ${error}`)
          })
      });
    }

for (let objkey in obj) {
      if (objkey === 'firsname') {
        let setname= obj[objkey]
         promise(setname).then();
      }
      else {
        this.columns[objkey] = obj[objkey];
      }
    }
```

**Error:** 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Failed to connect dbserver.

When calling the function and making db calls (asynchronous) not waiting for the query to be executed. Hence the test failed.

could anyone suggest the best way to handle this in synchronous manner.
note: New to promises

Comment: If you are using es6 use async-await to make it synchronous. `async function promise(setname) {` and call it with await, like this `let response = await promise('someName')`